# return data object to vue component using laravel 5.6 and axios

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js, axios

I am trying to build an availability carousel. It will show the days of the week, and what time someone is available. I am using Laravel and vue.js. I have done the web api, and I can get the data object following the route

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '/{area}'], function () {
    Route::get('/{tutor}/availability','Tutor\AvailabilityController@show'); 
});
```

with this in my availability controller

```
public function show(Request $request, Area $area, Tutor $tutor)
{
    $availability = $tutor->availability()->get();

    return response()->json([
        'data' => $availability
    ], 200);
}
```

That all works.

But when I try and pull it into Vue, nothing shows up. I can't seem to figure out what I might be missing.

I pulled the vue component into blade using the following, and passing in the area and tutor id

```
<availability area-id="{{ $area->slug }}" tutor-id="{{ $tutor->slug }}">
</availability>
```

and in Availability.vue, I think where I am going wrong is pulling the data in with props, but I am really not sure anymore.

```
<script>


  $(document).ready(function() {

      $("#availability").owlCarousel();

  });

  export default {

    props: {
      areaId: null,
      tutorId: null
    },
    data () {
      return {
        availability: []
      }
    },

    methods: {
      getAvailability () {

        axios.get( '/' + this.areaId + '/' + this.tutorId + '/availability').then((response) => {
          console.log(response.json());
        });
      }
    },
    ready () {
      this.getAvailability();
    }
  }


</script>
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Use response.data instead of response.json(), Also I believe you should use either mounted or created instead of ready in your component

Comment: That was bang on, thank you. If you wanted to post that as an answer I will accept it. I do have a follow up tho. To finish it off, i would change the console.log to this.availability = response.data; , and call it in the template like,  {{ availability.sunday_end }} . I think that's it, or do I still have to add it to data ()

Comment: The axios response object has the data field which contains the response from the request, in your case the json object i.e {data: availability} that you are returning from Laravel. To get the availability you have to use response.data.data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Axios response object has data field which contains the response from the server. To get the data use

```
response.data
```

Also for Vue 2.0 components use `mounted` instead of `ready` for when the component is ready. If you are only loading data from the server (and not manipulating the DOM) you can use `created` instead.

```
export default {

    props: {
      areaId: null,
      tutorId: null
    },
    data () {
      return {
        availability: []
      }
    },

    methods: {
      getAvailability () {
        var that = this;
        axios.get( '/' + this.areaId + '/' + this.tutorId + '/availability')
        .then((response) => {
          console.log(response.data); // should print {data: availability_object}

          // Set this component's availability to response's availability               
          that.availability = response.data.data;

          //OR
          //Add response's availability to the components' availability
          that.availability.push(response.data.data);
        });
      }
    },
    mounted () {
      this.getAvailability();
    }
 }
</script>
```

Comment: I still don't have something quite right. I correctly get the availability response, but nothing is being passed up to the template, and the data availability array in vue devtools is empty.

Comment: Thank you for all your help. I am so close, it shouldn't take me much longer.